# WPF DataGrid bound grouped items triggered too late

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I'm using a WPF DataGrid to show data that has been grouped two levels deep. Most of the XAML/code is based upon the MSDN example found on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407126%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

In addition to this example I've added a summary row below each second level grouping to do some summations. The user is able to change a row that affects one or more of the summations. Each time a user makes a change the summations should be re-evaluated directly in order to see the result of the change.

All functionality works fine except for the summary row update. After the user updates a field within the grid, the summation isn't re-evaluated. In fact, the binding of the summation is not triggered to call the converter to do a new summation. I found out that the trigger does come when changing focus to another part of the DataGrid (outside the changed row!) by clicking with the mouse.

**Let me clarify the relevant parts of my XAML/code...**

In order to get the rows belonging to this group I bind to the Items property and send them to a converter. Within XAML, this summary row shows up within the  element of the  element:

```cs
<GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
                                    Text="{Binding Path=Name}"
                                    FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="13"
                                    TextAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                        <ItemsPresenter Grid.Row="1" />

                        <!-- Grid that represents the summary row -->
                        <Grid Grid.Row="2">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <!-- for simplicity, only one summation field-->
                            <!-- This binding isn't updated unless I change focus somewhere outside the edited row -->
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,-2,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=Items, 
                                        Converter={StaticResource decimalGroupSumConverter}, ConverterParameter=AmountPerYear}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
```

The converter that is called for the summation:

```cs
public class DecimalGroupSumConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, System.Type targetType,
                          object parameter,
                          System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (null == value)
            return "null";

        ReadOnlyObservableCollection<object> items =
              (ReadOnlyObservableCollection<object>)value;

        if (parameter.ToString() == "AmountPerYear")
        {
            var sum = (from i in items
                       select ((ObservableCalculatedActivity)i).AmountPerYear).Sum();
            return string.Format("{0:c}", sum);

        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, System.Type targetType,
                              object parameter,
                              System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Next list shows my attempts to force the UI to update but without any success:

- Change the underlying sourcecollection by removing and re-adding the changed row
- Call the Refresh() method on the ICollectionView interface of the view.
- Re-sort the collection
- Refresh the datagrid according to this link: http://geekswithblogs.net/NewThingsILearned/archive/2008/08/25/refresh--update-wpf-controls.aspx

Please, can someone help me on this tiny but very annoying issue around updating the UI?

Comment: does "Items" property implements INotifyPropertyChanged interface ?

Answer (score 0):

Currently your binding is set to update the bound property when the focus is lost. To fix this, simply add `UpdateSourceTrigger` to your binding.

```
Text="{Binding Path=Items, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged ...
```

This will force `INotifyPropertyChanged` to be called as soon as the property changes, and therefore the Converter will also be called.

Comment: Thanks Mike, but this has no effect. I think the trigger should come from elsewhere because the user hasn't changed this field that is bound to 'Items'.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the underlying collection is in edit mode when the user is adjusting a field within the datagrid. These changes are kept somewhere in memory and are not yet flushed to the bound Items collection on group level within my XAML. To flush the changes and trigger the Items binding simply do a commit. In my case I first had to cast my ICollectionView to a ListCollectionView:

```cs
ICollectionView collectionView;
((ListCollectionView)collectionView).CommitEdit();
collectionView.Refresh();
```

Unfortunately there is a side-effect when committing: the concerning field leaves edit mode, the user should click twice to enter edit mode again.